# On handling any event related to login / logout activity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Currently, my application can track whenever user has logged in or out. The logging out activity is saved to database because User simply click a button. However, I would be interested in how to implement something similar but when user's ticket is no longer valid, either because it's been removed or expired.

I would like to handle any event (if possible) that is fired whenever user is no longer valid.

Is it possible to implement anything like this?

Cheers!

---

EDIT

I found two solutions. One uses BaseController--the code below from [Handle asp.net MVC session expiration](http://blog.tallan.com/2010/06/25/handle-asp-net-mvc-session-expiration/). This is simply what the author claims the easiest and working solution. First, is it a good idea to inherit all conrollers from a custom controllers? Second, I have already customized my own `[Authorize]` attribute. I don't know how all this together is going to work, and three, can i still have access to the cookie of a logged user where I hold UserID and some other data such as UserRole? And also it is not triggered automatically but whenver user trying to access and cookie is expired. It could be 6 hours later.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Check if session exists
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
        {
            //if new session
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                string cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                //if cookie exists and session id index is greater than zero
                if ((cookie != null) && (cookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                {
                    //redirect to desired session expiration action and controller
                    filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("SessionExpired", "Home");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        //otherwise continue with action
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

The second solution I found is based on `Global.aspx`'s function

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Account/Timeout");
}
```

but I read it only works when I use InProc. I don't know what that is, though.

Comment: What is your algorithm to decide the user session ? I mean, how do you know, when the user's ticket is no longer valid ?

Comment: You could look at session expiry events in web.config and global.asax

Comment: I simply test `FormsAthentication`. I take cookie value from `HttpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAthentication.FormsCookieName].Value` and check if it's null. If it's not, then I assume there's a session.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne Thanks Anthony. I'll try to find something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go with the filter `[Authorize]` you can add it as a global filter.

```
filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

Which is what your controller does too.

To answer your questions:

- Yes, if you are building a framework that impacts all controllers. There is no problem with inheriting from a base controller.
- Looks like the global filter is right up your alley.
- You can't access the cookie once the session expires since there is no client!
- When a session expires, the screen gets frozen to information they've already been authorized for until any subsequent request is made.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll have a go with global filter.